# cannot access google website only on Linux

Tags: fedora, internet

- My Problem

  - I cannot access **google** in **Firefox** 107.0.1 64bit, the latest, when I connect my WiFi at home.
  - I can access youtube, and Unix stack exchange.
  - I cannot access **zhihu**.
  - I can access **all of them** with the **same** WiFi, on **Windows**, or with my phone's **hotspot WiFi**.
  - "not able to access" means it cannot load the webpage, instead of error; It just kept me waiting.
- Basic Information

  - OS System : Fedora 37 WorkStation
  - Browser : Firefox latest
  - I have disabled the IPv6 in Firefox, not working.
  - I cannot ping google even I can access it normally when using the method written above like this: `ping google.com`
  - I changed my `/etc/resolv.conf` like this, still not working. I referenced [this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking), established a symbolic link to manually changed the `nameserver` (I don't really know if I have configure it correctly >_<)

```
nameserver 180.76.76.76
nameserver 114.114.114.114
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

and I've read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42932/periodically-cant-access-google) but it's not a solution for me.

Since that I can access it normally by the hotspot on my phone, I guess it might be the IP??(but I'm not sure, and I know little in such an area)

Any suggestions would be appreciated !!

Comment: Are you using a tunnel? Do you have an interface with MTU less than 1500 (as visible in the first line for each interface with `ip link`)? Are you sure it wouldn't work better with IPv6 (eg: your phone might be using IPv6)?

Comment: If you run `ping -n google.com`, does it successfully resolve Google's IP address? What if you try `ping -4 -n google.com`? If there seems to be DNS resolution problems, run `traceroute -n -T -p 53 8.8.8.8` and likewise to all your configured DNS server addresses. This is a TCP traceroute specifically to port 53, and if it fails, the output might provide useful clues.

Comment: @A.B Yes I am using clash for linux on my computer. I tried running `ip link show` and the output is below:`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:3e:26:70:d3:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/none`

Comment: @A.B I'm sorry I don't know much about this command... So if there is indeed a problem here?

Comment: @telcoM I tried running `ping -n google.com` and `ping -4 -n google.com`, but they both had a 100% loss rate. For `traceroute`,`180.76.76.76` took 30 hops(max) and didn't reach, but others all reached the target IP within 30 hops. Does this show the problem? Will the machine check these nameservers one by one if the 1st one is not reachable?

Comment: I thought about PMTUD problems (you do have a tunnel with MTU 1400) but as your ping doesn't work either, it's something else (but I don't know what).

Comment: So your first configured DNS server (180.76.76.76) is the one that fails most clearly... try commenting out or deleting that `nameserver` line from your `resolv.conf` file and exit & restart your web browser afterwards. Unless an application specifies a shorter timeout, a DNS query can take up to 30 seconds to time out. With a web browser, very few people have the patience to wait that long, especially as some page elements might trigger more DNS queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out with another search on this topic. I just run `sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 mtu 1492` and eveything back to work again. Still I don't know much about what's the matter in it, but luckily I can get access to all the websites normally.